# How to convert rows into columns in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to transform the first table, which is a result of a query, into the second table. At the first table, every value from the Y column has a value from the X, which can be the same. In the second table, I would like to reach that every X value will be a column with its own data from the Y column value. Could anyone send me a little note how to do that? Thank you.

```
Table First         Table Second
----------          ------------------
| X | Y  |          | A | B | C | D  |
----------          ------------------
| A | 1  |          | 1 | 2 | 6 | 10 |
| B | 2  |          | 1 | 3 | 7 | 11 |
| B | 3  |    ==>   | 1 | 4 | 8 | 12 |
| B | 4  |          | 1 | 5 | 9 | 13 |
| B | 5  |
| C | 6  |
| C | 7  |
| C | 8  |
| C | 9  |
| D | 10 |
| D | 11 |
| D | 12 |
| D | 13 |
----------
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Comment: Trickier than it looks. How would column d look if you only had 2 values,10 and 11?

Comment: @Strawberry I don't think this is a duplicate note that column a has 4 values of 1 in the second table but only 1 row in first table.

Comment: @p.salmon I maintain that it's near enough